# Проект iOS через Xib

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Добрый день. Есть такой вопрос, знаю он реализовываеться но немогу найти ничего что бы мне помогло.

У меня есть странички, на которых постоянно отображаеться одна и та же картинка через UIImageView  Я хочу создать картинка отдельным файлом. т.е. ".h" ".m" и ".xib" И задать все параметры там.

После чего, мне надо совместить маленький Img.xib и главным ViewController.Xib что б отобразить в нем готовую картинку. Подскажите как мне это сделать ???

Comment: "маленького img.xib" не бывает. Ваш .xib - это view, на него сверху бросаете в Interface Builder'e или прописываете программно UIIMageView который будет являться subview для Вашего основного представления

Comment: Сам ViewController я удалил перекинул в облость UIIMageView и присвоие его veiw по этом и назвал тут "маленьким"

Comment: пожалуй вы погорячились. Перетащите на поле опять View, бросьте на него UIImageView, в таком виде это будет гораздо проще.

Comment: т.е. у меня просто основание станет прозрычным и просто добавяться новый картинки ??? 

1 елемент справа, на одной View другой с лева на другой View оно прость обьедениться ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Синглтоны-то зачем? Делаете `Outlet UIImageView* myImage` в нужном классе, у ксиба привязываете этот класс как File Owner и прицепляете картинку к отлету, а далее где надо `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourXibName" owner:self options:nil];` , в других классах тоже можно определить отлет и так же загружать.

Хотя в описанном вами случае с единичной картинкой все-таки лучше найти другой способ, если речь только о том чтобы не писать по сто раз один и тот же код, то на можно сделать или #define, или категорию у UIImageView (пожалуй, самый верный способ), или сишную функцию возвращающую UIImageView*, это уж на что фантазии хватит. Чтобы файлик с определением этой категории\функции\дефайна был виден везде его можно добавить к -Prefix.pch

Comment: да да да, оно спаибо !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Напишите синглтон в котором будет храниться Ваша картинка. В каждый .xib файл добавьте UIImageView и например во `-viewDidLoad` каждого контроллера в котором Вы хотите отображать эту картинку грузите ее из синглтона(если Вы хотите чтобы картинка появлялась уже при загрузке вьюхи, если нет - то где-то в другом месте). Так же не забудьте импортировать синглтон в каждый .h где Вы эту картинку хотите видеть

Comment: А как мне задать координаты для отображения картики, ведь чуда не будет, мне надо укачать ее и указать где ее поставить.

Comment: `[[self backGround]image] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];` Просто задайте UIImageView пропорции соответствующие вашему изображению, иначе оно его растянет под свой размер по умолчанию